# git-gui: Moving keyboard focus to "changed files"

Tags: git, keyboard-shortcuts, git-gui

I'm trying to use my computer with keyboard only, without touching the mouse.

In `git-gui`, how do I move the keyboard focus to the list of changed files, so I can stage them (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) one-by-one? I know I can stage all changed files with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>, but it doesn't work for staging newly created files.

Comment: If you're trying to do it all with the keyboard, why bother with git gui? You could just run `git add .` from the top level of the repo to add all modifications and newly created files.

Comment: I'm aware of `git add .`. I like using the GUI and I like using it with the keyboard only.

Comment: Fair enough. Just a rare preference - my keyboard-only tendencies are exactly why I use CLIs not GUIs. And I have no idea about an answer - I can't even get focus in there by clicking on it, so I doubt there's much hope with the keyboard...

Comment: Very pertinent question. This bothers me too, always.

Comment: I just experienced that if one starts git gui and just used `CTRL+T`, the focus stays at "Unstaged Changes". Manually clicking anywhere else moves the focus away. No way to recover. - I filed an issue for git for windows. Let's see, if an expert of git gui can take over - https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/859

Answer (score 2):

You can control a few things with the keyboard:

- using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + *<1st-character-menu-item>* to open a menu, e.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> for the Commit menu
- there are a bunch a shortcuts available like <kbd>F5</kbd> for refresh
- using <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> you jump around the buttons Rescan to Push, New Commit to Amend Last Commit and to the Commit Message box

However I found no way to jump to the [Un]Staged Changes boxes and also to [un]stage hunks or lines.

Answer (score 1):

A patch was made to enable `ALT+1` (and numbers up to 4) to focus the widgets of the git-gui interface:

- `ALT+1` focus "Unstaged Changes"
- `ALT+2` focus "Staged Changes"
- `ALT+3` focus the diff view
- `ALT+4` focus the commit message dialog

You can read more about the implementation discussions [here](https://public-inbox.org/git/CAGr--=LZ9TSM9v0SZOi_mj1t8se0Ck-nDHkwum3kC8uz9HKW6A@mail.gmail.com/)